# Awk equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, awk, gpio

I'm trying that my php script reads a configuration file. I'm able to open the file and load each line of it to each array position with the file command. However, now I need to analyse each line but could not find a way to read each field, like an awk equivelent.

The configuration file is like this:

```
GPIO; Direction; Active_low; Default_value; web_page; Description
1; out; 0; 0; yes; ficheiro1
2; out; 0; 0; yes; ficheiro2
```

My php script is this:

```
$conf=file('/etc/gpio.conf', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
for ($i=1; $i <3; $i++)
{
 echo" conf $i: $conf[$i] <br />";
 $GPIO=$1stfield_of_conf[i];
 $Direction=$2ndfield_of_conf[i];
 $Active_low=$3rdfield_of_conf[i];
}
```

What I would need would be something like awk '{print $1}', but capable of read a PHP array...

Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: Found a way, with the explode command:

    $conf=file('/etc/gpio.conf', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    for ($i=1; $i <3; $i++)
    {
    echo" conf $i: $conf[$i] <br />";
    $temp_array=explode(";", $conf[$i]);
    echo "GPIO: $temp_array[0]";
    echo "web: $temp_array[4] <br />";
    }

Comment: Or I can post it as answer, I could use the Brownie points ;-)

Comment: as you wish, I just couldn't answer myself because stackoverflow required me 8h before doing so

Comment: @user2433937 Done ;-) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, give this a whirl:

```
$conf=file('/etc/gpio.conf', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    for ($i=1; $i <3; $i++)
  {
echo" conf $i: $conf[$i] <br />";
    $temp_array=explode(";", $conf[$i]);
echo "GPIO: $temp_array[0]";
echo "web: $temp_array[4] <br />";
  }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, with the explode command:

```
$conf=file('/etc/gpio.conf', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 

for ($i=1; $i <3; $i++) 
{
 echo" conf $i: $conf[$i] ";
 $temp_array=explode(";", $conf[$i]); 
 echo "GPIO: $temp_array[0]"; 
 echo "web: $temp_array[4] ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't actually need them in an array, you could use list() in combination with explode().  If the values only exist within this loop iteration, you may find code more readable if they have meaningful names, rather than $temp_array[3].

```
$conf = file('/etc/gpio.conf', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

for ( $i = 1; $i < 3; $i++ )
{
    echo" conf $i: $conf[$i] ";

    list(
        $GPIO, $Direction, $Active_low, $Default_value, $web_page, $Description
    ) = explode( ";", $conf[$i] );

    echo "GPIO: $GPIO\n";
    echo "Direction: $Direction\n";
    echo "web: $web_page\n";
}
```